# Querying Ahoy Gem Events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, ahoy

I am using the Ahoy gem in a Rails 4.2 app. Ahoy Events stores events with a number of text attributes and a `properties` attribute that contains data I want to query. For example here is the last event I return via the rails console

`>> Ahoy::Event.last
  Ahoy::Event Load (3.8ms)  SELECT  "ahoy_events".* FROM "ahoy_events"  ORDER BY "ahoy_events"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Ahoy::Event id: "fffff17f-44e6-41d7-9c32-fa895338f54e", visit_id: "6b05b1ca-3863-46da-9c48-a3ab5fa4a9ee", user_id: 1, name: "$click", properties: {"tag"=>"a", "page"=>"/conversations/2", "text"=>"View", "href"=>"/conversations/2"}, time: "2015-08-23 13:25:51">`

How would I retrieve all events where properties['text'] = 'View'

I have tried `Ahoy::Event.where(:properties['text'] => 'View').count`

which returns: 
```

> > Ahoy::Event.where(:properties['text'] => 'View').count
> >     NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:59:in`block in expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:58:in `each'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:58:in`expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:957:in `build_where'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:584:in`where!'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:574:in `where'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:10:in`where'
> >         from (irb):13
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`start'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`load_dependency'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/bin/rails:8:in`'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`block in load'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/development/blackops/.bundle/gems/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/.rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
> >         from /Users/dariusgoore/.rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
> >     ```

I have looked online for querying hash attributes without success. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahoy::Event actually doesn't return anything useful. To get all records in an array return object, you need to use `Ahoy::Event.all`.

So what you actually need to do is something along the lines of this:

`Ahoy::Event.all.select { |event| event.properties['text'] == "View" }.size`

The run time isn't going to be that nice but I think this is what you need.

Comment: you are right, the run time is nothing nice but i'll take it.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Ahoy::Event.where("properties ->> 'text' = 'View'")` Way faster to use valid JSONB query syntax.